# Javaslang - how do I join two successful Trys?

Tags: java, try-catch, vavr

I'm still learning Javaslang/Vavr, so excuse the ignorance. The project I'm working on is stuck on **Javaslang 2.1.0**.

My question: is there a more "Functional" way (as opposed to imperative style) to structure my code to join multiple Trys **only** once they are successful?

I want to Try each input independently, the idea being to get as much as possible error information - I do **not** want to stop on the first error encountered (so `orElse()` etc. won't do the trick). But once no errors are found any more, I want to do something further involving all of the inputs.

My current code looks like this (suitably anonymized):

```java
Try<BigDecimal> amountTry = Try.of(this::readNumber)
    .map(BigDecimal::valueOf)
    .onFailure(this::collectError);

Try<Currency> currencyTry = Try.of(this::readString)
    .map(currency -> currencyLookup(Currency.class, currency))
    .onFailure(this::collectError);

if (amountTry.isSuccess() && currencyTry.isSuccess()) {
    sale.setAmount(Amount.of(amountTry.get(), currencyTry.get()));
}
```

Can you suggest a pattern to replace the `if()` with something more in the functional style of programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javaslang/Vavr construct that you are looking for is the *for comprehension* construct, which is accessible through the `API.For` methods.

```
import javaslang.control.Try;
import static javaslang.API.For;
...

For(amountTry, currencyTry)
    .yield(Amount::of)
    .forEach(sale::setAmount);
```

That is, if both `amountTry` and `currencyTry` are non-empty, it creates an `Iterable` by yielding a result value on the cross-product of the two iterables, and performing an action on each of the resulting elements by invoking a `Consumer`. Here is the same in lambda form with explicit input types, if it helps you better understand it:

```
For(amountTry, currencyTry)
    .yield((BigDecimal amount, Currency currency) -> Amount.of(amount, currency))
    .forEach((Amount amount) -> sale.setAmount(amount));
```

Later versions of the library have overloads of the for comprehension for `Try` which will return a `Try` instance instead of `Iterable`, which makes the API a little bit nicer if you want to stay in `Try` domain.